# updating a variable inside an if condition within a list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

i tried my best to write the following code in a list comprehension but ended up getting wrong

```
for i in range(1,n+1):
    L.append(i+(k*sin))
    if(i % (k) == 0):
        sin*=-1


return [i+(k*sin) if(i % (k*2) == 0) sin*=-1 for i in range(1,n+1)]
```

Comment: Your code is doing more than just creating a list, so a list comprehension is a bad fit for it. While you may be able to bend over backwards enough to do it, there's really no point in doing so.

Comment: What do you want exactly here? Every `k` you want to commute the signal of `sin`?

Comment: You are not just making list but also checking a condition and doing sin*=-1, dont make a list comprehension for that.

Comment: I disagree with you @deceze... what he wants to do is in fact very well represented by a list comprehension. The only thing is, he translated the mathematical expression of what he wants into a conditional statement, when that was not the best approach. That is why it appears as if his code is doing more than just creating a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a list comprehension, but you should take a different approach.

Let's say `k == 3`: then your sequence will look like this:

```
1 + k*sin
2 + k*sin
3 + k*sin
4 + -k*sin
5 + -k*sin
6 + -k*sin
7 + k*sin
8 + k*sin
9 + k*sin
 ...
```

Basically, you just want a list comprehension that looks like

```
[i + n*sin for i, n in zip(range(1, n+1), ???)]
```

The question is, what do we replace `???` with to get our sequence of repeating `k` and `-k` values?

The `itertools` module provides several tools for generating this:

- `repeat` - repeat a value some number of times
- `chain`  - concatenate two or more sequences into a single sequence
- `cycle` - cycle through the values in a sequence repeatedly

In this case, it's

```
cycle(chain(repeat(k, k), repeat(-k, k)))
```

giving you

```
from itertools import repeat, chain, cycle


[i + n*sin for i, n in zip(range(1, n+1), cycle(chain(repeat(k, k), repeat(-k, k)))]
```

`zip` ensures we only take a finite number of values from the infinite sequence.

Another approach is to use another tool from `itertool`, `islice`, to take only the first `n` values from the cycle. Then we don't need `range` anymore; we can use `enumerate` to number those values from `1` to `n` instead.

```
from itertools import repeat, chain, cycle, islice


[i + n*sin for i, n in enumerate(islice(cycle(chain(repeat(k, k), repeat(-k, k))), n), start=1]
```

---

Both read better if you define `ks` first:

```
ks = cycle(chain(repeat(k, k), repeat(-k, k)))
[i + n*sin for i, n in zip(range(1, n+1), ks)]
```

or

```
ks = cycle(chain(repeat(k, k), repeat(-k, k)))
[i + n*sin for i, n in enumerate(islice(ks, n), start=1)]
```

---

You can also optimize this a bit by repeating the value of `k*sin`, rather than performing the multiplication for each element of the list.

```
ks = cycle(chain(repeat(k*sin, k), repeat(-k*sin, k)))
[i + n for i, n in ...] # using either zip or enumerate as before
```

Comment: chepner so what would be the best way to write the code and does using itertools consume increase storage and time?

Comment: To be honest, I'd still with the `for` loop; there's no reason to replace every loop that constructs a list with a list comprehension. `cycle` needs to remember which elements it is cycling over, so it will require O(k) memory: not an issue if `k` is "small", but something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to mathematically formulate your problem a little bit better, than it can easily be represented as a list comprehension.

In essence, you want the a formula for the signal of `sin` which is dependent on the index `i` and on `k` that will invert the signal every `k`. That is represented by `(-1) ** (i - 1) // k`.

So, if you include that into your code, you should arrive at exactly what you want:

```
return [i + (k * ((-1) ** ((i - 1) // k)) * sin) for i in range(1,n+1)]
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Let's say k == 3: then your sequence will look like this:

1 + k*sin
2 + k*sin
3 + k*sin
4 + -k*sin
5 + -k*sin
6 + -k*sin
7 + k*sin
8 + k*sin
9 + k*sin   this is exactly what i wanted but the equation which you gave was working for k==1 but not other values                                                                                                                                      i initially took sin value as 1 and did sin*=-1 after so when i tried i didnt get the correct output

Comment: i want this output when                                                                                                                                                                         n=10 and k=5
       [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]                                                                                                                                      but instead i got                                                                                                                                                         
       [1, -3, 3, -1, 5, 1, 7, 3, 9, 5]

Comment: @SDK You are right, there was a typo on my answer (forgot a parenthesis). I have added it now.

Comment: that's so freaking awesome i couldn't even understand how you got this so fast.Could you please suggest anything to improve my math

Comment: also sin value is 1 so using sin variable is useless

Comment: Thanks mate. In terms of improving your math, it depends a lot on what you have studied so far. In this particular example what helped me arrive at the solution was my background with limits and series (which I studied under calculus on my engineering bachelors). Also, there are some very good youtube channels which give you very good insights into mathematical thinking. One such example is [3blue1brown](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYO_jab_esuFRV4b17AJtAw/videos).

Comment: oh, ok... so sin stands for signal I guess... in that case it can indeed be removed....

Comment: dude thanks a loot it would be really helpful if you recommend any channels for books for math in programming